# How to add and subtract hours and minutes

Tags: datetime

Is there a package which adds and subtracts hours and minutes. I mean, I would like to define `\newcommand{\time}{10:00}` and use it in the document as

```
\time + 00:20 = 10:20
\time + 01:30 = 11:30
```

My idea is modify the command `\time`, and so all the others times in the document will be modified.

Comment: What does `\time` refer to? Any time that you set, or the current time? Would you want to perform calculations where "hours" and "minutes" may be anything within the range 0..99 (as in `\time + 12:76` or something similarly bizarre)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the following code the macro `\setcurrtime` sets the current time to be used later whenever `\currtime` is used.

The macro `\currtime` prints the current time; if given an optional argument, it will offset the current time by it (the offset is assumed positive).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcurrtime}[1]{%
  \set@time\curr@hour\curr@mins#1\@nil
}
\def\set@time#1#2#3:#4\@nil{%
  \def#1{#3}\def#2{#4}%
}

\newcommand{\currtime}[1][00:00]{%
  \begingroup
  \set@time\new@hour\new@mins#1\@nil
  \count\z@=\curr@mins\relax
  \count\tw@=\curr@hour\relax
  \advance\count\z@\new@mins\relax
  \advance\count\tw@\new@hour\relax
  \ifnum\count\z@>59
    \advance\count\z@-60
    \advance\count\tw@\@ne
  \fi
  % we have to use \count\z@ and \count\tw@ before
  % ending the group and printing the result
  \edef\x{\endgroup\two@digits{\count\tw@}:\two@digits{\count\z@}}\x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcurrtime{10:00}

\currtime

\currtime[00:20]

\currtime[01:30]

\setcurrtime{14:54}

\currtime[00:05]

\currtime[00:06]

\currtime[00:07]

\end{document}
```

Just by way of example, I used `\setcurrtime` twice, in order to show that the limit cases are treated correctly.

[image]